# How can I compare the effectiveness of a regression model for different datasets

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, prediction, error

I have a multiple linear model that works on different datasets. suppose that the first dataset produces `y` in range of [1,100] and the second one in range of [1, 1000].

I can't simply compare the `MAE` for the two datasets. If `MAE` for the first one is `2` and for the second one is `20`, I'd say the model is consistent, but I could not find a scientific way to show this:

There is no such thing as a `Normalised MAE`. I can consider `NRMSE` using `RMSE / (ymax - ymin)`, but I was wondering if there are any better ways to compare the effectiveness of the same model on different datasets? 
I am also aware of `MAPE` and `MASE`. Just wondering what is the best practice in reporting a **scale-independent forecast error metric**.

I am interested in the theory: which one of these work for my case: `NRMSE`, `MAPE` or `MASE`? 
I'm also using Python.

Comment: Mean absolute percentage error?

Comment: I have seen examples that claim "MAPE puts a heavier penalty on negative errors than on positive errors", but there is also `sMAPE` as a solution, but I fear `sMAPE` is not as common as something like `NRMSE`. So, again, I would like to choose the most common metric that is familiar to someone who is not necessarily a statistician.

Comment: I believe, "MAPE DOES NOT put a heavier penalty on negative errors". Actually the famous example in Makridakis (1993) paper is wrong. It is actually discussed in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064841/understanding-forecast-accuracy-mape-wmape-wape So, there is this arguments around MAPE that made think twice. Any further input on that?

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299712/what-are-the-shortcomings-of-the-mean-absolute-percentage-error-mape/299713#299713

Comment: Thanks, I read that. I think none of the problems apply to my case though. Also, in terms of, `NRMSE`, shall I use the min and max of the whole data? or should it be "Split, scale your training data, then use the scaling from your training data on the testing data."
: as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302871/do-you-apply-min-max-scaling-separately-on-training-and-test-data